# Why does my cursor randomly disappear while programming in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is making developing for Android very annoying...  I'll be typing then copying and pasting some text but the cursor disappears.

Comment: That works for me,
Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: here is the solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45802863/2173890
dont forget to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue on Linux and OS X.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78384