# Android Studio: Text cursor disappears/gone after open some other class or pasting text in different classes

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

**Android Studio:** Text cursor disappears/gone after open some other class or pasting text in different classes.
Cursor is randomly disappear while coding in Android Studio. Currently using version 1.5.1
Some time cursor is only visible in one file either in java or xml
Right click is working but cursor is not visible in java/ or xml file so I am not able to type the code.

**Observed scenario**
The text cursor is not visible or the cursor is gone when I open a different file (e.g. ApplicationTest.java instead of activity_main.xml) the cursor appears again.

**Expected scenario:**
The text cursor should be located after the insertion point.

**Action taken to solved**
I used synchronize, restart Android Studio…..  but not able to get solution. 
I am using window 7 and I have cleared temp

**R&D** https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78384

I stuck to this problem so please help me. Appreciate, if anyone can help to troubleshoot.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue.

Comment: got anything or not ??

Comment: I didn't get any solution.. i am not sure but it may be due to RAM

Comment: I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 25):

> command + O
>   type some words
>   esc

cursor appear, works for me

Answer (score 17):

Just update the date time to proper date time.

**Permanent workaround: 1**

After studying a lot, I found that my system time was incorrect. (On my pc, it was because of windows time service error and not because of CMOS battery. while in some cases CMOS battery may cause this.).

1. Just update correct the date/time and the cursor will be visible.
2. If it is still not, close android studio, update correct and start android studio again.

**Permanent workaround: 2**

Reinstall windows and immediately install antivirus before installing any other software. (Mome malware can affect the working of time service in PC.). (Those who keep antivirus setup file/s on PC itself or USB device, they must check out whether the setup is clear in itself.).

**Workaround: 3**

On the left pane in android studio, strangely, all my classes were shown as singleton while they weren't.

1. I pressed multiple combinations multiple times of alter / shift / ctrl / mouse clicks to to check whether any key is stuck (which seldom happens).
2. I put Android Studio into power save mode: `android studio -> file -> power save mode` and tried to work again.
3. I corrected my system date (it was 2 days behind than current.)
4. Restarted the PC. The issue is resolved.
5. Disabled power save mode.

**Temporary solution:**

No need to close project or android studio.

Click on the scroll button on the right of the editing pane or on suggestions yellow lines somewhere else on the same vertical scroll bar line.

[image]

Comment: Damn, you're right! In my case, it was caused by the de-synchronized system time. I don't think I would ever find it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have same problem too
but I solved with this trick..

**Go to File-> Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Now cursor should appear..

Answer (score 1):

When the cursor disappeared, you can press `Insert` key on your keyboard, then the cursor will be appeared again.

Comment: Insert key is not working in my case and according to me insert is work when cursor size is  almost double size, bold and cursor visible but in my case cursor is not visible

Comment: Oh but in my case it is working when the cursor dis appeared, just click on Editor area and then press Insert key.

Comment: According to my knowledge Insert Key is basically used when cursor is block cursor(cursor size is almost double size, bold and cursor visible) i.e when text is overwritten. Make me correct if i am wrong

Comment: Yeah you are right, but when the cursor was dis appeared I also search a lot for this, but did not find any solution, then when I pressed on Insert key it was working, but I don't why it does not work with you.

Answer (score 1):

**Go back and check again.. You might find cursor there..**

I am using 3.1.2 of AS on Mac. I faced the same problem after pasting multiple classes in AS. While cursor was gone I was able to make text selection. I checked StackOverflow for the solution and reached this question. After reading a couple of answers I went back to AS workspace and cursor was there...

Answer (score 1):

In **Android Studio 4.2** this issue still exists. I've deleted the settings file of the android studio folder by folder to find out which file is causing the error. In windows If you navigate to

`C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.2\options`

[image]

you will see an `other.xml` file. You can delete this file. This might fix the issue (at least it fixes it in my case). You can also comment out or delete this line in the `other.xml` file to fix the issue

`<property name="Source Code Editor With PreviewLayout" value="Preview only" />`

[image]

Comment: This might work I will try it next time. I hope that the issue will be solved soon in AS.

Comment: I just deleted the line and restarted Android studio and the cursor is now OK.

Comment: Glad to know that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533758/9317258) answer for faster solution.

**Original Post**

In my case the cursor was disappearing when I opened a file/class from [recent files dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#recent_files). When I deleted a file from the list and opened it again (for example: ctrl + n -> go to class) the cursor was there but then opened it again and the cursor was gone.

The solution for me was to **[restore default settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65037846/9317258)**  from Android studio (invalidate caches/restart didn't help me).

**Edit October 2021**

- It happened again (AS 2020.3.1 running on Ubuntu 20.04)
- After restoring to default settings AS makes a backup of your settings files to `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3-backup`.
- I just deleted new files in `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3` and copy there the old files and it works! (I didn't proceed through the initial setup of AS, but open my project, then exited it, replaced old settings files and then run again.)

Answer (score -1):

Close the android studio, not just the project instead the IDE. then open it again, wait till it build and then cursor appears.

Comment: So according to you i have  to restart it again and again?

Comment: Nope, Not again and again, For me it has resolved for one shot

Comment: It work but again after sometime it create this problem

Comment: Yes I see the same thing. Closing and re-opening android studio fixes it for a while, but eventually the cursor goes again.

Answer (score -2):

You might have column select on by accident, turn it off with 
    ALT + SHIFT + I

Answer (score -4):

this happens because some other **text editor** is open on **PC**........**close** that text editor/other instance of android studio and this will be **solved**....