# Android Studio: cursor lost

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Andorid Studio 1.5.1 for a week now, and I'm experiencing a very frustrating bug. My cursor is disappearing randomly when I'm coding. I searched the web for a solution, but I only found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784539/android-studio-text-cursor-disappears-gone-after-open-some-other-class-or-pasti) here in this site and he is not getting any solution. Please, I need to fix this in order to be productive. Any help with this issue will be very appreciated.

Comment: here is the solution. don't forget to up-vote this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45802863/2173890

Answer (score 2):

That works for me,
Invalidate caches and restart